# Laravel relationship, do I need extra table for relating comments

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4, relationship

I need some logical help here, I have an article table and a comments table. when a user comments I store it inside the table:

```
public function up()
{
  Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->string('user_id');
      $table->string('comment');
      $table->integer('article_id');
      $table->timestamps();
  });
}
```

I don't know if I need to add another table such as `user_comments` in orther to make this relationship, it actually sounds pretty dumb to me, but the problem I run into here is that I get the comments with a basic query like:

```
$comments = DB::select("Select * from comments where article_id=$articleID");
```

But than I have hard time showing `username` and stuff so I need a simple relationship in between, anybody has idea about how can accomplish it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to add another table. You just need to define proper relationships. In `Article` model:

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

In `Comment` model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

To get `username` use [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$article = Article::with('comments.user')->find($articleId);
```

Then iterate collection in a view:

```
@foreach ($article->comments as $comment)
    <div>{{ $comment->comment }}</div>
    Comment author: {{ $comment->user->username }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: That is great, but can't I just do `@foreach ($article->comments as $comment)` and than  `$comment->user->username` once I pass the  `article` ?

Comment: Btw did you mean `Article::with` ?

Comment: @Nikonah yes, I mean `Article::with`, thanks, fixed. If you'll not use `with()`, `$comment->user->username` will generate N additional queries. So, if you're loading 100 comments, Laravel will generate 101 query to DB instead of 2.

Comment: Perfect. It works as it was supposed to be! I'm marking your answer as correct. but one little question. lets say I had another table where the `id` is same as `user ` id and I call id `userprofil`, I want to access that table instead of `user ` table, but everytime I try to do that the forigen keys and stuff gets messed up, any opinion on that would be dramatically helpful for me.

Comment: @Nikonah it really depends on what relationships are between `Comment`, `User` and `Profile` models. If you'll not be able to fix this new problem, create a new question and post all related code (relationships, query).

Comment: I see, there is actually none, when a user registers I creat `userprofile` as well and their id's are the same, I know it is kinde dumb but at least that table does not include password and many other things and has some information which user does not have. I think if I create relationship between comment and userprofile than I might be able to get informtion from that table, don't you think ?

Comment: @Nikonah if a profile is related to a user, you shouldn't create a relation between profile and comment. Just use nested eager loading, like `comment.user.profile`